# Odd error in ShellFile.FromFilePath

Tags: c#, shell, windows-api-code-pack

Sometimes I am getting following error:

> An item with the same key has already been added
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2.Insert(TKey key, TValue
>   value, Boolean add)    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.PropertySystem.ShellPropertyDescriptionsCache.GetPropertyDescription(PropertyKey
>   key)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.PropertySystem.ShellProperties.PropertySystemVideo.get_FrameWidth()

This happens randomly when I am trying to read `FrameWidth` of [ShellFile](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/1.1.0):

```
ShellFile shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(_file.FullPath);
            if (shellFile.Properties.System.Video.FrameWidth.Value != null) //<- fails here
```

Does anyone know why this could happen?

Comment: What's the next line of code after the if? Are you adding file names to a dictionary as their key?

Comment: @user9993 next line after if is just assignment of that value to local variable (another get), but that doesn't matter because it failing at first read which is within IF condition `shellFile.Properties.System.Video.FrameWidth.Value != null`

Comment: I had a similar issue, but more frequent in release mode, less or none in debug mode. It turns out there are some bugs in my code, not ShellFile.FromFilePath per se. There is a great [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548/Surviving-the-Release-Version) about the common problems in release version.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is only an issue in my compiled code. The interpreted version works fine. In turn this has be double checking all references can be found and are consistent between interpreted and compiled code